# Orderby a HashSet in an Object in Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-objects

I have a pretty complex Linq statement with multiple joins, but am having a problem with an orderby statement.

I think I can reduce the question down a bit, but will expand if needed.

First my object has the following properties:

`myObject.ID` This is a basic Int

`myObject.BrandName` This is my `HashSet<string>`.

I need to sort my Object by the BrandName using the lowest or highest value depending on if I am sorting ascending or descending.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you mean order by the minimum or maximum value in the set? Fortunately that's easy - even if it'll perform fairly badly:

```
orderby myObject.BrandName.Min()
```

or

```
orderby myObject.BrandName.Max() descending
```

(Or vice versa, depending on what ordering you want.)

Comment: Awesome.  I don't know what I like more as I dig... Linq or StackOverflow.com :-)

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for you?

```
// replace with mo.BrandName.Min() to sort the other way
Func<MyObject, string> getBrand = mo => mo.BrandName.Max();

var q = from myObject in myObjects
        let b = getBrand(myObject)
        orderby b
        select myObject;
```

Comment: There's no need to use a "let" clause here. You do need to make it Max() or Min() rather than Max or Min though.

Comment: I thought that the OP needed the syntax as a part of a bigger expression, in which case it might have been useful to know about... Apparently not...

Comment: While not useful for me, it may help others.  Thanks for the effort and info.  I can't +1 you... as I have no idea if what you have will work :-)

Comment: @Clarence: It would - it's basically equivalent to mine. You can still have the `Func<MyObject, string>` bit and use `orderby getBrand(myObject)` though - no need for the `let` clause unless you need the value elsewhere (in which case you might as well only find it once, of course).